# Enabling offline use of >1GB HTML5 site

Tags: html, windows-8, offline

A large HTML5 site with currently a bit under 1GB (but growing) of content needs to be able to be viewed offline in fullscreen mode by a restricted amount of users. The user base will consists solely of the customer's organization's salespeople, all using a Win8 hybrid tablet. The site is essentially a product catalog and contains tons of images, text and currently about a dozen videos. The salespeople occasionally need to use the site in places where network access is not available.

We have tried the following approaches:

**Open the page from the local hard drive** - As there are lots of pages, they have been split to separate files and are loaded when needed with AJAX. However, AJAX requests to the `file://` URI scheme are rejected by Chrome and Firefox. IE10 allows them, at least after adjusting security levels, but the whole site runs extremely slow this way and would need major troubleshooting and maybe a full overhaul.

**Specify an HTML5 application cache manifest** - Chrome fails to cache any videos, IE10 fails to cache anything over 50MB. Firefox caches the site nicely up to 1GB, but that seems to be a hardcoded limit and further videos can not be added as that would make the site too large to fit in the cache.

**Wrap the site to an HTML5 executable application using Visual Studio** - This works otherwise fine, but occasionally an `unload` event is triggered for some unknown reason and the app exits. I haven't been able to locate what is causing the event to be raised as the code runs without errors in debugging mode until the event appears from seemingly out of nowhere.

**Turn it into an .HTA** - The resulting "application" runs really slow and we can't hide the window's title bar or the Win8 dock.

We've been able to bypass the security restriction of the first option in Chrome, but the hack needs to be run again with administrative privileges each time Chrome is started. The customer's IT department strongly objects to this solution.

Is there some better solution that we have missed? Or is one of the ones we've tried clearly superior to the others and should be examined further?

Comment: Maybe you can write your own small web server or use xampp?

Comment: @JanHommes: I actually ran that one by the customer's IT staff, with no luck. I even suggested dual-booting to Linux. They weren't amused.

Comment: Did you create a Windows Store app for #3?

Comment: Have you asked the question: Do they really need to see the full resolution images offline?  If you had lo-res 'backup' images that were replaced using JS with hi-res ones if the app is online.  This may allow you to fit into a more usual offline app size.

Comment: @robertc: I haven't, but the images aren't as much of a problem as the videos. I might suggest using lower quality or shorter versions of them and replace with the full versions if online, in case a better solution can't be found.

Comment: Yeah, when I said images I really meant media, but I think the approach overall would be a valid one if they allowed it.  Keep the size of the application cache under control overall and allow full fidelity when online.

Comment: I'm not sure why the .HTA would run slowly, but did you try minimizing the title bar with <hta:application border="none" windowstate="maximize">?

Comment: I'm quite puzzled why the first option runs slowly and why it hits security restrictions. I test-deploy my website via local file access and wring out the glitches before I "publish" it. Accessing pages and content via  file:/// is extremely _fast_, and I haven't run into any security restrictions at all. All the URLs in my pages look like 'href="foo/bar.html", and I let the browser fill in either http: //mysite.tld/foo/bar.html" or "file: ///localsite/foo/bar.html" automatically depending on where the first page came from. (Explicitly specifying the leading part may _not_ work well.)